# Creating a Key Path from a computed var in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `fetchedResultsController` where I'd like to add a keypath for `Date` so I don't have a section for every second of the day. Simple enough, I thought...I'll create an `extension` for `MyEntity`

```
extension MyEntity {

  var dateForSection: String {
    get {
      let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
      dateFormatter.dateStyle = .long
      if let time = self.time {
        return dateFormatter.string(from: time)
      }
      return "Unavailable Date"
    }
  }
}
```

Then, on `MyViewController` in the `fetchedResultsController` lazy var declaration, I declare the `frc` as follows:

```
let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: #keyPath(MyEntity.dateForSection), cacheName: nil)
```

I get this compiler error:

> Argument of '#keyPath' refers to non-'@objc' property 'dateForSection'

In Googling the issue saw some Swift bug reports from 2016, but I haven't seen any solutions to this. How would I get around this?

**Addendum**

I've tried adding `@objc` in front of the `var` declaration. I've also tried adding `@objc dynamic`, closing Xcode, nuking derived data from the command line, rebooting Xcode, rebooting my machine, etc.

Comment: That's the first thing I did and the error persisted after cleaning caches, nuking derived data, etc.

Comment: Yes. Just double-checked build-settings.

Comment: Can't reproduce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem. I whipped out a Core Data project with a Group class auto-generated from my entity, and added a computed variable:

```
extension Group {
    @objc var yoho : String {
        return "yoho"
    }
}
```

Then I modified that same line in my lazy fetched results controller initializer:

```
    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(
        fetchRequest:req,
        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext,
        sectionNameKeyPath:#keyPath(Group.yoho), cacheName:nil)
```

It compiles. I don't know why yours doesn't.

On the other hand, a `#keyPath` is nothing but a string generated for you, and what's expected here is a string, so if you really can't get it to compile, just put `"dateForSection"` and be done with it. Of course that doesn't mean it will *run* without crashing, but at least it will compile and you can move on.

Comment: Ugh! I know PRECISELY what I was doing wrong. Specifying `get` was my problem. I tried adding a setter, too...that didn't help. Removing the setter getter and making it a return var got me across the finish line. Thank you!!

Comment: No, I don’t see why that would matter. In my code the `get` is implicit, that’s all. If that really does matter, it’s a bug in Swift!

Comment: Can't reproduce, once again. I added a `get` wrapper to my test code and it still compiles.

Comment: The crucial part for me was to add "@objc". It does not produce an error omitting "@objc", however, the property never got computed, and therefore the section name/return string was empty.